# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) with cocoapods swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift2, cocoapods

I'm trying to compile my project in swift with cocoapods and I'm getting this error:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/platis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Platis-dazbrsqztcftsbapiewpxklnxdhp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ToastSwift'
ld: framework not found ToastSwift
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm trying to install ToastSwift from [this](https://cocoapods.org/pods/ToastSwift)

Comment: Are you trying to compile using the workspace created by cocoapods?

Comment: Have you tried quitting then restarting the application, or running a clean then build?

Comment: Do this : ls -l ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Platis-dazbrsqztcftsbapiewpxklnxdhp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator from Terminal and give us the output. Include in your question. This should be *after* doing a full clean and full build of the workspace.

Comment: We also need the exact contents of your Podfile, and an "ls -l" of the "Pods" directory within your Project directory, and also the output of pod --version, and also the output of 'pod install` and to be assured that it has successfully run. I have found some pods require cocoapods release 0.39 and others require 1.0.

Comment: Try deleting your derived data folder and rebuilding.

Comment: @BaseZen output is: total 0 drwxr-xr-x  27 platis  staff  918 Aug 20 23:47 Platis.app
drwxr-xr-x   6 platis  staff  204 Aug 20 22:40 Platis.swiftmodule

Comment: @Daniel Pereira The CocoaPod is not installed or configured to be part of the project. As @Leonardo said (and to expand), `pod install` creates a new `.xcworkspace` file. You must then open the project using this file exclusively, **not** the `.xcodeproj` file. A screen capture would also be helpful with all of the 'Pods' area on the lower left fully expanded.

Comment: @BaseZen opening the project with .xcworkspace solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: OK written up as an answer in case this proves helpful generally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a CocoaPod, it creates a new launch file: *Project*.**xcworkspace**

Only this file contains the Pod configuration. Technically speaking a workspace is a collection of projects; each Pod gets its own project because every Pod has its own configuration requirements and resources. You can no longer use the `.xcodeproj` to launch your project, otherwise none of the Pod information will be found.

If you fail to do this, you'll get all manner of compile and link errors.

You missed this line of the docs:

https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html

> Open the MyApp.xcworkspace that was created. This should be the file you use
>   everyday to create your app.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem deleting your derived data folder, rebuilding and opening .xcworkspace instead .xcodeproj

Comment: Did you delete the entire derived data folder or just the folder in derived data that was for your project?

Comment: I deleted entire derived data folder